# Save output in processing every X seconds

Tags: processing

Hi I'm using processing and want to know if there is a way I can automatically save my output every X amount of seconds?

Any help would be great!

Comment: what's your "output" ?

Comment: When I click play on processing it builds a generative design

Comment: are you using https://processing.org/ ?

Comment: Please precise in your question you are using processing.org. + when you answer a comment, add a @ before the name to make sure the person is noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for saveFrame() method.
Inside your draw() method, you can save a screenshot of your visual output.

```
void draw() {
  // YOUR CODE
   ...
  // Saves each frame as screenshot-000001.png, screenshot-000002.png, etc.
  saveFrame("screenshot-######.png");
}
```

More info: https://processing.org/reference/saveFrame_.html

And for take screenshot every X seconds:

```
int lastTime = 0;

void draw(){
  // YOUR CODE
  ...
  // 1000 in milisecs, that's 1 sec
  if( millis() - lastTime >= 1000){
    saveFrame("screenshot-######.png");
    lastTime = millis();
  }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly thank you! Is there a way to define the seconds it takes the screenshots.  For example every 5 seconds?